# Changing Response type to str, bytes, or os.Pathlike

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, psycopg2

I am trying to automatically download/copy a csv file into a postgres database, and using this kaggle one as an example. 
I am running into a problem with the object type, currently it is a response and I want to make it so it will work.

I have been playing around with using shutil and copying the files, but so far not making much progress.

## step 1 import libaries and setup connections

```
import psycopg2
import requests
import csv
import os

conn = psycopg2.connect(....)
cur = conn.cursor
```

## step 2 create table in database

```
cur.execute("""
CREATE TABLE real_estate_data(
id integer PRIMARY KEY,
data DATE,
rentorbuy VARCHAR(255),
location VARCHAR(255),
address VARCHAR(255),
zipcode VARCHAR(255),
description VARCHAR(255),
type VARCHAR(255),
nbofrooms DECIMAL(3,2),
surace VARCHAR(255),
floor INT,
price VARCHAR(255),
source VARCHAR(255))
""")
```

## step 3. use requests to obtain a csv from a url and copy that data from a table (in this case real estate data)

```
url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/fredgirod/web-crawler-for-real-estate- 
market/downloads/Output.csv/3'
onlinedata = requests.get(url, verify =False)
onlinedata.raise_for_status()

with open(onlinedata, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f,'real_estate_data',sep=',')

conn.commit()
```

TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not Response

Answer (score 0):

you need to read `onlinedata.text`

```
with open(onlinedata.text, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f,'real_estate_data',sep=',')
```